# Mybatis query execution is too slow

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I created a project with eclipse maven.

And I use `Spring Boot 2.2.2 Release` and `mybatis-spring-boot-starter 2.1.0`, `Postgresql 13`.

It's built as a monolithic application, running over 50 insert queries every second. And
the table has more than 10,000 data.

Postgresql's max-connection value is 1,000.

**The problem is that select query execution using mybatis is very slow (The query is very simple, but it takes 3 seconds.).**

The speed of purely query execution is about 200 ms, but it takes 3 seconds to get the result value through mybatis.

I tried applying fetchSize="1000" but the result was the same.

When I tested it, stopping the insert query every second made the select query faster.

Does fetchSize work in mybatis 2.1.0? How can I speed up queries?

Comment: Could you please share the SQL that is executed, the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, and most important the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, setting)` for the SQL statements involved? All in plain text, as an update to your original question. Without this information it's impossible to help you.

Comment: You need to look somewhere else to solve your issue -network, application, etc. By your own admission the query requires 0.2 seconds (yea that maybe slow) out of the 3 seconds total. That means 2.98 seconds in not in the query. Even if the query is improved by an order of magnitude no one is likely to notice any/much improvement.